# Fill picker content from array react native

Tags: react-native, picker

i am using local storage (AsyncStorage) .. and i want to display all content from local storage to `<Picker>` .. and i create a function .. the function return all data as array .. this is my function

```
 getElementsInLocalStorage = async () => {
        try{    
            var x = new Array();

            let all_keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();



            for(i = 0; i <= all_keys.length;i++ ){

            x[i] = await AsyncStorage.getItem('one_person'+i);

            }

            return x;
             }

        catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    }
```

and i need a solution that display the result using `<Picker>`

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to set the stored data into your state (like I did in componentDidMount), if you have a selected key by default just set it to selectedKey state and pass it to selectedValue props and then iterate over your data.

When an item is selected just set the key of that item into your state.

I created a code snippets for you than can be helpful:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Picker,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        key1: 'data1',
        key2: 'data2',
        key3: 'data3'
      },
      selectedKey: 'key1',
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedKey}
              onValueChange={key => this.setState({selectedKey: key})}>
            {
              Object.keys(this.state.data).map(key => (
                  <Picker.Item key={key} label={this.state.data[key]} value={key}/>
              ))
            }
          </Picker>
          <Text>Selected data: {this.state.selectedKey}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

You can get your selected value using:

```
this.state.data[this.state.selectedKey]
```